Warning upgrading from Almalinux 8 to 9: Leapp detected a processor which is no longer maintained in RHEL 9
Using sudo leapp upgrade and then checking the output with nano /var/log/leapp/leapp-report.txt, there's a warning.
If the processor is not longer maintained in RHEL 9, does that mean the almalinux server cannot be upgraded? Or does that mean there is a software support risk?
Title: Leapp detected a processor which is no longer maintained in RHEL 9.
Summary: The following processors are no longer maintained in RHEL 9:
     - IVYBRIDGE_X

Key: 93f6cf039f01095a59ebaf581ced33316e034ef8


Leapp warnings are just that, warnings: they provide information that the user should take into consideration, but they don’t prevent upgrades. If Leapp identifies an issue that prevents an upgrade, it indicates an “inhibitor”.
As far as CPUs are concerned, RHEL 9 supports x86-64-v2 and above, which includes Ivy Bridge CPUs. I imagine Alma Linux follows suit. So your server can be upgraded. As for support, you’d have to check with Alma Linux; Leapp’s message refers to RHEL, not Alma Linux, but Red Hat’s support policies don’t apply to Alma Linux.
